# Better performance in Lucene Or SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, search, lucene

I am using `PostgreSQL` database.

Having a table named metadatavalue with structure is as below:

```
metadatavalue_id    integer  Primary Key Auto Increment
metadta_field_id    integer  Foreign Key
text_Value      varchar
text_lang       varchar
place           integer
```

When anything gets submitted or added an item with almost 25 metadata fields
is created.

The metadatavalue table already contains around

> One Hundred Fifty Thousand(150000)  records.

I am implementing an auto complete feature for a field let say "Author" 
which is stored as metadata_field_id in the table.

When I query the table on PgSQL prompt, it takes almost 1 or 2 seconds to return the result.

QUERY:

```
SELECT metadatavalue.text_value AS author, count(metadatavalue.text_value) AS count
   FROM metadatavalue
  WHERE (metadatavalue.metadata_field_id IN ( SELECT metadatafieldregistry.metadata_field_id
           FROM metadatafieldregistry
          WHERE metadatavalue.text_value LIKE 'Pra%' AND metadatafieldregistry.metadata_schema_id = 1 AND metadatafieldregistry.element::text = 'contributor'::text))
  GROUP BY metadatavalue.text_value;
```

As its for auto complete the query might run 4-5 times when users enters value.

So, I am thinking to implement LUCENE based search.

In which,At First creating an index from back end and then on each new item
creation running a thread to index the new item.

I want to know that whether [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) would be better choice or 
SQL can be optimized.

EDIT:
There is another table which contains metadata fields and it is used as Foreign Key (metadatafieldregistry.metadata_field_id) in metadatavalue table for the value.

Comment: Before switching to Lucene, why not properly index the table? Seems like such a radical measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say any database will handle at least a million rows gracefully if proper indexing is done, there is no reason for you to get into Lucene or Solr which will introduce you to new tasks like synchronization of your indexes with most current state of the DB.

Also, Lucene or Solr are very great for free text searching. This means if you search for "Bob Marley" on your Lucene "documents" then you will get all the document which has "Bob Marley", "Marley Bob" or only "Bob" and only "Marley" or even "Bob...lot of text...Marley". So using Lucene also depends on what kind of use cases you are trying to cover.

From the query you have shown I feel you will get good performance if you index `metadatavalue.text_value` `metadatafieldregistry.metadata_schema_id` and `metadatafieldregistry.element` columns. Also try converting your query to a join rather then an `in` query.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and brief intro of Lucene. I will check with suggestions on query and get back with updates

Comment: Earlier query was taking almost 2 seconds for the first run and then 600 ms for subsequent run on the database console
I have changed in to Inner Join and nnow its takes almost 510 ms on first run and around 300 ms and even less than that on subsequent run.Thank You, your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 1):

With a prefix query on such a small dataset, both Solr and PostgreSQL should perform very well provided that the required columns are properly indexed.

Comment: The query is just an example. Let say If I type "Pr" in the text box then it should query all the rows having starting value "Pr" for a given field

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the schema of `metadatafieldregistry` table (in fact you say you have just one table, but your query uses two)

Look at the `explain analyze` output to see what the query plan is, and what is taking up the time to scan. Your subquery is correlated, which almost definitely isn't a good plan: in general, the schema smells of EAV. You may find a partial index helpful, to produce an index containing only those text values that you want to do a prefix search on (probably restricting  `metadata_schema_id` and `element`)

Comment: +1 for the subquery point. The query was written by someone else,I was using it. Edited question for other table details. Thank You